# Swift 3: How to convert from [String: AnyObject] to [String: String]?

Tags: swift, swift3

I want to convert a `[String: Anyobject]` dictionary to `[String: String]` dictionary?
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot convert a dictionary directly from `[String: AnyObject]` to `[String: String]`: since `AnyObject` can hold different types of values in the same dict, each such value entry isn't necessarily convertable to `String`.

Instead, you need to go over each key-value pair and conditionally perform a value conversion to `String`, if possible. E.g.:

```
// (example) source dict
let dict: [String: AnyObject] = ["foo": "1" as AnyObject,
                                 "bar": 2 as AnyObject,
                                 "baz": "3" as AnyObject]

// target dict
var targetDict = [String: String]()
for (key, value) in dict {
    if let value = value as? String { targetDict[key] = value }
} // targetDict: ["foo": "1", "baz": "3"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply, you can do it this way:

```
if let castedDict = dictionary as? [String: String] {
    print("Converted successfully: \(castedDict)")

} else {
    print("Failed to cast the dictionary")
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but castedDict was nil.

Comment: This casting will fail if the dictionary you're trying to cast can not be cast to `[String: String]`. I updated my code to make that more clear.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help.